# how to send a mail to group of person by using Javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Can anybody tell me how to send a mail to group of person by using JavaMail?

I have tried but I am getting error at `SendEmailToGroupDemo()` and at `start()` method.

```
public class MailJava {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      // Create a SendEmail object and call start 
      // method to send a mail in Java.
      SendEmailToGroupDemo sendEmailToGroup = new SendEmailToGroupDemo();
      sendEmailToGroup.start();

     }

     private void start() {

      // For establishment of email client with 
      // Google's gmail use below properties.
      // For TLS Connection use below properties
      // Create a Properties object 
      Properties props = new Properties();

      // these properties are required
      // providing smtp auth property to true
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      // providing tls enability
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      // providing the smtp host i.e gmail.com
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      // providing smtp port as 587
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

      // For SSL Connection use below properties

      /*props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
         "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");*/

      // Create Scanner object to take necessary 
      // values from the user.
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please provide your Username for Authentication ...");
      final String Username = scanner.next();

      System.out.println("Please provide your Password for Authentication ...");
      final String Password = scanner.next();

      System.out.println("Please provide Email Address from which you want to send Email ...");
      final String fromEmailAddress = scanner.next();

      System.out.println("Please provide Email Addresses to which you want to send Email ...");
      System.out.println("If you are done type : Done or done");

      // ArrayLists to store email addresses entered by user
      ArrayList< String> emails = (ArrayList< String >) getEmails();

      System.out.println("Please provide Subject for your Email ... ");
      final String subject = scanner.next();

      System.out.println("Please provide Text Message for your Email ... ");
      final String textMessage = scanner.next();

      // Create a Session object based on the properties and 
      // Authenticator object
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, 
        new LoginAuthenticator(Username,Password));

      try {

       // Create a Message object using the session created above
       Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

       // setting email address to Message from where message is being sent
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress));

       // setting the email addressess to which user wants to send message 
       message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, getEmailsList(emails));

       // setting the subject for the email 
       message.setSubject(subject);

       // setting the text message which user wants to send to recipients
       message.setText(textMessage);

       // Using the Transport class send() method to send message 
       Transport.send(message);

       System.out.println("\nYour Message delivered successfully ....");

      } catch (MessagingException e) {

       throw new RuntimeException(e);

      }  
     }

     // This method takes a list of email addresses and 
     // returns back an array of Address by looping the 
     // list one by one and storing it into Address[]
     private Address[] getEmailsList(ArrayList< String > emails) {

      Address[] emaiAddresses = new Address[emails.size()];

      for (int i =0;i < emails.size();i++) {
       try {
        emaiAddresses[i] = new InternetAddress(emails.get(i));
       }
       catch (AddressException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
      return emaiAddresses;
     }

     // This method prompts user for email group to which he
     // wants to send message
     public List< String > getEmails() {
      ArrayList< String > emails = new ArrayList< String >();

      int counter = 1;
      String address = "";
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      // looping inifinitely times as long as user enters 
      // emails one by one
      // the while loop breaks when user types done and 
      // press enter.
      while(true) {

       System.out.println("Enter E-Mail : " + counter);
       address = scanner.next();

       if(address.equalsIgnoreCase("Done")){
        break;
       }
       else {
        emails.add(address);
        counter++;
       }
      }

      return emails;
     }
    }

    // Creating a class for Username and Password authentication
    // provided by the user.
    class LoginAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
     PasswordAuthentication authentication = null;

     public LoginAuthenticator(String username, String password) {
      authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
     }

     @Override
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return authentication;
     }
}
```

Comment: Comments on methods should be done as JavaDoc and not line comments, for better readability. What error do you get? If it is an exception, please add the full stacktrace.

Comment: 'i am getting error' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
   // setting the email addressess to which user wants to send message 
   message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, getEmailsList(emails));
```

With this:

```
   // setting the email addressess to which user wants to send message
   for (String emailBcc : emails) {
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(emailBcc));
   }
```

I've had problems with setRecipients() before, but never with addRecipient().

If you keep having issues, we'll need the stacktrace with the exact error / exception you're getting.